# dbaascli - non-interactive

Tags: oracle, exadata

How can I use `dbaascli` without being prompted for SYS password and TDE password?
I would like to input these values from a file.

If I issue this command, I am being prompted.

```
/bin/dbaascli database create \
--dbname C1B02 \
--dbUniqueName C1B02S \
--dbSID C1B02 \
--createAsCDB yes \
--pdbName PDB1 \
--dbCharset AL32UTF8 \
--dbNCharset AL16UTF16 \
--sgaSizeInMB 4096 \
--pgaSizeInMB 1024 \
--oracleHome /u02/app/oracle/product/19.0.0.0/dbhome_1 \
--oracleHomeName OraHome1 \
--tdeConfigMethod FILE \
--executePrereqs no
```

Thank you